# Wordpress core update via wp cli

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for ways to update WP core via WP CLI.
There are lots of resources and information on how to do it. Most of them suggest to execute the below command to update the WP core:

```
wp core update
```

Some suggest that if it is needed to updated the DB, we can do it via:

```
wp core update-db
```

How I can know that I need to update the database as well after executing core update?

Comment: If there's no database updates required, the process won't cause any errors. It's safe to just run `wp core update && wp core update-db` anytime you do an update.